# Azure VNET - Accessing VNET Resources from WebApp

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-network

I have deployed a VNET on Azure. I have also set up a Point-to-Site connection following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) tutorial. I need 3 things on this Network.

1. VM Instance for MongoDB Docker.
2. WebApp API(ExpressJS) which should treat (1) as local address
3. Connect my Local machine to VNET to manage my VM Instance

I managed to deploy (1)

I successfully connect my machine (3) to the VPN and can access (1) on local IP 10.1.0.5:PORT using Mongo DB Management tool.

For WebApp API (2). I have followed all the necessary steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). And Azure Portal show that the App is connected properly.

[image: Azure WebApp Screenshot]

According to [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Websites-VNET-Integration-with-Chris-Compy) I should be able to connect the VM (1) . However I cannot access the local resources from the WebApp API (2).

My Connection String for WebApp API(2) is of the following format:

mongodb://[username]:[password]@10.1.0.5:[port]/[db-name]

What can be the possible reason?

Comment: did you allow that port to be accessible by webapp? on the nsg level?

Comment: If you are referring to Subnet Association then I have done that.  Do I need to explicitly define a Inbound/Outbound Rule too?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#troubleshooting if you scroll down a bit you will find a list of common errors

Comment: nameresolver.exe hostname responds with
*** Can't find <my-host-name>.exe: Non-existent domain

Comment: from MongoDB Linux instance using SSH, i tried Nmap tool and it scanned 2 hosts on the network. One seems to be a WebApp as it has all relevant posts open

Answer (score 0):

since this seems to be specific to your setup, I would recommend reaching out to support so the support team can do a thorough investigation.

-- Anavi N [MSFT]